# Beginner hangman game in java

Tags: java

Does anyone have an idea on how I can change underscores to the correct letter if it is guessed correctly? This is the method I have setup to display the answer as underscores:

```
private void printWordStatus() 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++)
    {
        String answer = this.answer;
        String word = "";
        char c = answer.charAt(i);

        if (c == ' ')
        {
            word += c;
        }else 
        {
            word += " _ ";
        }
        System.out.print(word);
    }

}
```

Lets say that the answer is "Monday" this method will produce "_ _ _ _ _ _" and it will recognize when someone types the correct letter by not counting towards incorrect guesses. I just don't know how to get the underscores to display "M _ N _ _ Y" instead if they guessed M,N,and Y correctly.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Take the indexes of the letters that were correctly guessed from the original `String` and replace the underscores at those indexes with the letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tryALetter method you introduce avery letter that has been tested in a list. 
 You can configure more for example: If the list has more then 3-4 letter tested that are not in the word ->>Game over.

```
public List<Char> letterTested;
    private void tryALetter(Char oneLetter){
          for ( int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++){
                     if (oneLetter == answer.charAt(i){
                           letterTested.add(oneLetter); 
                     }
          }
    }    

    private void printWordStatus() 
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++)
            {
                String answer = this.answer;
                String word = "";
                char c = answer.charAt(i);

                if (c == ' ')
                {
                    word += c;
                }else 
                { /* here you test if the letter is in the list 
                   if it is in the list, you print the letter, not the "_" */
                  for(int j = 0; j < letterTested.lenght(); j++){
                       if (c == letterTested.get(j)){
                                word += c;
                    } else {
                       word += " _ ";
                    }
                  }
                }
                System.out.print(word);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hold an array of booleans with the length of the word.
Let's call it `guessed_letters`, at you initiate it all to false.
Every time the user guesses a letter, you set to True the value on the boolean array.

Then at your printing loop, you could check for every index if it is guessed of not by simply doing `if(guessed_letters[i])`. If guessed you print the letter, else you print `_`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can hold your word in a Map. And mark each letter guessed or not. And then just use a boolean value to present `_` or character.
Hope that's what you need.

Tell me if you need more.